# JDK and IDEA ignores $HOME on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Every time I launch IntelliJ IDEA it ignores the `$HOME` environment variable and creates `.java` and `IdeaProjects` in my `/home/user` directory.

Why is this? How to force it to use `$HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA doesn't use the HOME variable to determine where your home directory is.
Instead it uses the java property [user.home](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to determine your home folder.

To change this behaviour, you can edit the `IntelliJ IDEA_home\bin\idea.properties` file:

```
idea.config.path=/tmp/config
idea.system.path=/tmp/system
idea.plugins.path=/tmp/plugins
```

For more information look at the [JetBrain's help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html)!

Comment: What about .java/ directory? It seems like it created by jdk itself.

Answer (score 0):

JDK, as it always done in Java world, deliberately ignores $HOME and instead uses it's own user.home property, which can be set using _JAVA_OPTIONS:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.home=/tmp/java-home`